# Create a sorted array by mistake using .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to make something that works as `Set()` using a couple tools that I learned. It worked, but I noticed a bug: it sorted my array! Can explain me someone why, please?

Here's my code:

```js
function uniteUnique(...arr) {

  let array = arr.flat()
  let newArr = [];

  console.log(array) // [ 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1 ]

  let myMap = array

    .map(elem => {

      if (!newArr.includes(elem))
        return newArr.push(elem)
    })

    .filter(Boolean)

  console.log(myMap) // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

I know that for you might be too simple, but I ask so I can understand what is happening here.

Comment: push returns the number of elements pushed, not the actual value

Comment: a) try logging `newArr` in addition to `myMap` 2) try passing in arrays of characters

Comment: I'm guessing what @user120242 says right but i also couldn't understand why `map` giving `index`'s instead of actual `child`'s

Comment: @HalilÇakar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push "The new length property of the object upon which the method was called."

Comment: @user120242 Thanks again! I wasn't aware that push is returning `length`. THX!

Comment: @Bergi , i don't understand what you tell me to do... 
a) what do you mean by 'logging'? b) where to pass an array of characters?

Comment: @Gheorghe I mean `console.log(newArray)` (or `console.log(myMap, newArray)`). And `uniteUnique(['a', 'c', 'b'], ['e', 'b', 'a', 'd'], ['b', 'a']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 console.log(myMap) // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

The result of your log is the **number of pushed elements** but accidentally, you thought they are sorted.

Also, if you return the mapped list you will end up with an array that contains an integer and boolean values. Instead of this, you need to return `newArr`.

Your code will be like this :

```js
 function uniteUnique(...arr) {

    let flattedArray = arr.flat()
    let set = [];

    flattedArray.forEach(elem => !set.includes(elem) && set.push(elem))

    return set
}


const set = uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
console.log(set)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code MyMap holds your newArr length as array.push returns the length of your array
so every time it returns the count:
for example if you tried to run this code

```
  let newArr = []
  console.log(newArr.push(20)) // the output is 1
```

and that's what your myMap holds => the length of your newArr

so if you want the filtered array you should use newArr

```
  let array = [ 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1 ]
  let newArr = [];

 let myMap = array.map(elem => {
  if (!newArr.includes(elem))
    return newArr.push(elem)
 }).filter(Boolean)

 console.log(newArr)   //[1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

Comment: what he should return from the function ? `newArr` or `myMap` ?

Comment: from what i understand, i should return `newArr`